# Dúvida MVC em Android

Tags: android, mvc, mobile

Gostaria de saber o seguinte, no desenvolvimento Android usando MVC, para cada Activity eu tenho que ter um Controller e talvez um DAO? Ou posso usar a mesma classe de Controller que controla duas Activity? E perde muita performance ou pesa muito criar tantas classes assim? O model sei que posso usar em outros controller e Activity.

Também estou tendo que passar sempre meu controller para o DAO, pois preciso esperar um callback em uma thread e dai depois do termino peço para o DAO chamar um metodo desse controll que foi passado por parametro. Por exemplo `controller.retornoCadastroUsuario(exception)` aonde nesse metodo ele verificaria a exception e possivelmente pede para exibir algo usando algum metodo da view (que também foi passada como parametro no controller). **Está certo isso?** Ando lendo bastante a parte de MVC - MVP no Android mas fico confuso quando estou usando um Banco de dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, vc pode usar a mesma controller ou dao para quantas activities forem necessárias sem "pesar" (dependendo claro da forma que é feito) como em qulquer outra plataforma.

Quanto ao callback na sua activity vc pode implementar uma interface da sua controller. Algo como:

```
public class MyController {

    public MyController(OnControllerListener onControllerListener){
        this.onControllerListener = onControllerListener;
    }

    public interface OnControllerListener {
        void onControllerCallback(String someString);
    }

    private OnControllerListener onControllerListener;

}
```

Quando ocorrer o evento que dispara o callback `onControllerListener.onControllerCallback(String someString); //Ou qualquer outra coisa que queira na activity`

E na activity ao instanciar a controller:

```
MyController myController = new MyController(new MyController.OnControllerListener() {
    @Override
    public void onControllerCallback(String someString) {

    }
});
```

Comment: E como eu tinha comentando na outra resposta, é certo passar uma Activity (view) para um Controller? Para que sempre que necessário alguma modificação, alerta, dialog, etc (coisas da view) o controller possa chamar, dependendo do que o controller decidir.

Comment: Não diria que é errado, entende? Mas o padrão seria o que tentei demonstrar com a interface.

Comment: E se eu quisesse usar por exemplo um LoginActivity e um CadastroActivity, com metodos distintos, mas usando o mesmo Controller. Dessa forma eu teria que criar 2 interfaces no Controller?

Comment: Sim. Outras opções seria vc ter um Bundle como argumento de onControllerCallback(Bundle bundle) com seu objeto ou passar um json e deserializar nas activities. Sua thread recebe o que?

Comment: Amigo, peço desculpas, não vou conseguir te responder por que sou leigo no assunto dev Android.  Outra coisa, preciso que se possível me responda uma coisa. Por cadastrar um usuario então ficaria (view -> controller -> model -> DAO (a partir daqui faz o caminho inverso levando o resultado)). E para fazer esse caminho inverso eu teria que também criar uma interface no DAO, e implementar ela no Model (ou até mesmo no Controller) quando chamar o DAO? Esse metodos que serão implementados seriao o de retorno? Pq o retorno do DAO vem em uma Thread para mim e não consigo dar "return" direto.

Comment: Tranquilo, disposto a ajudar no que precisar. A sua controller então recebe o valor da DAO, certo? Isso já está acontecendo?

Comment: Sim, a Controller iria receber o valor da DAO com o retorno se deu ou não certo o cadastro do usuario. Estou o usando o banco de dados Parse, e quando uso o metodo de cadastrar ele "abre em outro Thread" e assim dessa forma não consigo dar um return "direto", teria que chamar algum metodo para o Controller ficar sabendo se deu ou não certo o cadsastro do usuário.  Por isso antes estava passando o Controller por parametro DAO. Agora já não sei se crio uma interface também ou tento algum método que me ajude a esperar o Thread do metodo de cadastrar terminar ai sim dar um retorno.

Comment: Sim, para "facilitar" teria que fazer o mesmo na dao. Nesse caso tbm não vejo problemas em ter a interface somente na dao. Na controller somente passaria essa inteface diretamente para a dao. Sem declarar essa interface na controller. A não ser que precise manipular os dados.

Comment: Ok. Então tudo isso que você me passou seria o real MVC? Temos a Activity que é a view, criar um Controll e uma interface dentro dele, e no controll tem o construtor que recebe essa interface e a partir dele chama metodos do view. E no DAO também termos uma interface que servirá dessa vez para o controller fazendo com que o DAO retorne o resultado para o controller por meio dessa interface? Pelo que entendi é isso, até consegui implementar dessa forma.

Comment: Outra coisa, a interface do View pode contar mais de um metodo? Ou tem que ser 1 para cada 1 interface?

Comment: Sim. Os detalhes das interfaces é por conta da necessidade dos callbacks. Pode ter mais métodos sim, o quanto precisar.

Comment: Òtimo, muito obrigado, parabéns pelo tempo gasto. Vou levar pra vida esse aprendizado, haha!

Comment: Boa! Deveria ter abrido um chat, mas não sei fazer isso rs

Comment: Nem eu, haha. Mas te mandei convite do facebook, agradeço novamente. Abraços.

Answer (score 1):

Em relação ao DAO, ele é referente ao modelo, ele não tem "nada a ver" com sua Activity, se você precisar acessar 3 modelos, que existem 3 DAOs diferentes, você fará isso independentemente.

Comment: E a questão do controll? È necessário ter um para cada Activity?

Comment: @Hamon, brother, só respondi a respeito do DAO porque é um pattern que pode ser usado em vários projetos, e eu uso direto nos meus projetos web, não é usado somente em projetos mobile. 
Sei um pouco de Android, mas não conheço `Controll`

Comment: Acho que os controlls seriam para cada entidade. pois os métodos podem ser chamados onde quer seja preciso. Por exemplo, na Usuario_Controller, tem o método logar() que pode chamado na activity login, e não na activity de cadastro

Comment: Se for um Controller, responsável por passar informações do modelo pra view, pra Activity, eu concordo que seja um pra cada modelo também.

Comment: @adventistaam a entidade que você seria um Model? Mas e eu teria que criar nesse exemplo dois construtores no controller aonde um recebe a LoginActivity e outro LoginActivity para acionar metodos de visualização (que ficam na activity) por dentro do controller. Teria algum problema ser assim? Por isso a duvida de criar um controller para para Activity.

Comment: Sim. O Model. Geralmente eu uso o controller sem construtor

Comment: Se não usa construtor então você passa a Activity como parametro no metodo no controller?

Comment: Na verdade eu uso o controller para se comunicar com o DAO. Tipo só mando os valores mesmo. Qual seria a sua ideia de passar a Activity?

Comment: Passar a Activity para o Controller para pode chamar algum metodo de mostrarMensagem ou irParaNovaActivity (que fica na activity) que são coisas que vão envolver a camada de visualização "não podendo" ser executada diretamente pelo Controller. Por exemplo, controller faz as verificações e agora precisa abrir um dialog, então esse metodo para abrir o dialog estaria no view.